# How to use single google map for multiple activities?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm creating taxi application like uber.
How can I use Single google map for all screens.

Check Default google map application. It is using same map for multiple screens like home screen, routing screen, navigation screen, share location to friend screen etc.

Is this possible with BaseActivity? If possible then how?

Comment: "It is using same map for multiple screens like home screen, routing screen, navigation screen, share location to friend screen etc." -- they are all one activity, most likely.

Comment: If they are using single activity then how they are managing BottomSheet, Toolbar etc. Because if I put all code in same screen then code will be very complicated.

Comment: You can do it one activity that hosts map and fragments to work with it.

Comment: Can you please give any code example?

Comment: "If they are using single activity then how they are managing BottomSheet, Toolbar etc" -- none of those require multiple activities. A bottom sheet is a type of dialog. A `Toolbar` is a widget, no different than a `Button` or an `EditText`.

Comment: I am looking for the same solution. Did you find a solution for this? If so can you tell me. I know I can do this within the same activity using fragments but afraid that the task navigation will become difficult

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fragments` to achieve your goal by splitting screen to `map fragment` and different modules
we can navigate to different `fragments` instead using `activities`
because fragment gives you flexibility to navigate to different activities by allocaing some space in screen
for more details you can use this link
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: Can you please give any code example? I mean where to put map and how to access it in multiple fragments?